# How do I get rid of the red boxes around the links in the TOC?

Tags: org-export, pdf

I wanted to get rid if the red boxes in TOC that we obtain when exporting org to pdf. The red boxes looks absolutely ugly and spoil the appearance of the entire document.

[image: ugly red boxes around toc links]

Comment: That might be how your pdf viewer app indicates links. Try opening the same pdf with a different pdf app

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan Nops. Found a solution, added it as answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Following the links given [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2012-04/msg01167.html), you can get rid of the ugly red boxes by adding the following line in the beginning of your org file:

`#+latex_header: \hypersetup{colorlinks=true}`

[image: Red]

If red isn't your color, then add the following line:

`#+latex_header: \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue}` for a blue color.